# How to list the sensors available on werable device after claiming the device through Google fit Ble API?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, sony, google-fit

Unlike other questions about wearable device with Google fit, this is different as I cannot meddle with the wearable as I am using a Sony smartband2, and not an android wearable device.

I have successfully implemented the Fit Ble Api as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
public static final String TAG = "BasicSensorsApi";
private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
private boolean authInProgress = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }

    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.BLE_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    //connecting
    mApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Google Client api Connected");
    BleScanCallback bleScanCallback = new BleScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDeviceFound(BleDevice bleDevice) {
            Log.i("Bluetooth Device found", bleDevice.getName());
            PendingResult<Status> pendingResult =
                    Fitness.BleApi.claimBleDevice(mApiClient, bleDevice);
            Log.i("Claim", pendingResult.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanStopped() {
            Log.i("Bluetooth", "Scan stopped");
        }
    };

    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.BleApi.startBleScan(
            mApiClient,
            new StartBleScanRequest.Builder()
                    .setBleScanCallback(bleScanCallback)
                    .build());
    ResultCallback mResultCallback = new ResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {

            Log.i("Bluetooth", "Pending Result");
        }
    };
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(mResultCallback);
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
    } else if (i
            == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
        Log.i(TAG,
                "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed");
    if (!authInProgress) {
        try {
            authInProgress = true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

        }
    } else {
        Log.e("GoogleFit", "authInProgress");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
        authInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (!mApiClient.isConnecting() && !mApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth");
    }
}
}
```

This successfully finds my band. I now want to list all the sensors available in this.

I am guessing I will need to use the [Sensors Api](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors) but how do I list the sensors specifically only on this band? (Using only the Sensors Api does **not** list my device as a Data source).
Is there some other approach that I have overlooked?

Comment: You may check this [List available data sources](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors#list_available_data_sources) documentation to obtain a list of all available data sources on the device and on companion devices using `SensorsApi.findDataSources` method. Then use the `DataSource.getDevice` method to get information about the device for a data source. The device information is useful to distinguish from similar sensors on different devices, show the device information from a sensor to the user, or process data differently depending on the device.

Comment: This method does not list my fitness tracker device. The ble api lists this device, but when I use findDataSources from Sensor Api it lists only my phone which I'm running the app on. 
If you have any other suggestions, let me know.